# Why have a path argument when there is cwd

Tags: patterns-and-practices, command-line, cli

When writing a program that uses a working directory, e.g., PostgreSQL data directory or download target for wget, is there an advantage of having a CLI argument (or an environment variable) for such a directory? If the program doesn’t use any other path for its business, isn’t the current working directory enough, or even the right choice? Because otherwise, why the concept of a cwd even exists?

I see a possible drawback in running the program in an environment that doesn’t have control over the cwd. Also, using this invisible and non-explicit path may be confusing and unintuitive.

Are there other disadvantages of the approach only using cwd? Or pros of having an argument or a configuration value instead, not using cwd at all?

Comment: I actually think this can be objectively answered. Not so fast with the close-votes, please.

Comment: How would e.g. `rm` function if it only used the cwd?

Comment: @JBRWilkinson `rm` operates on files (or directories), but does not use a “working path” for its operation in the sense e.g. Git does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The authors of a command line utility do not have control over the execution environment, or how the utility is invoked. You, as the command line user, might know that the current working directory is sufficient for your needs, but the program has no such insight. This leaves authors of command line utilities a limited number of options:

- Make the user (e.g., you) specify the exact path as an argument.
- Get the path from the execution environment.
- Use the current working directory.
- Use a configuration file

  - And then choose one of the previous three options to identify the configuration file.

Which option gets chosen depends on what the command line utility does, and its expected use cases. Typically, the command line utility will require a path argument. It might optionally fall back to the current working directory if no path argument is supplied. This is left up to the discretion of the program authors.

Some command line utilities require multiple file arguments. Defaulting to the current working directory might not make any sense. For example, KDiff3 is a text comparison tool that can be invoked from the CLI. It takes up to 3 file paths for comparison, and an optional fourth path as the output for merging the files. There is no way to provide intelligent defaults here for the file or folder paths.

Any time you provide an "intelligent default" for a program, remember that what seems like an intelligent default to you (as the program author) might not seem so obvious to an end user. You already noted one of those issues in your question:

> ... using this invisible and non-explicit path may be confusing and unintuitive.

These challenges are further compounded by the fact a command line utility doesn't need to be invoked by a human. You can invoke utilities as part of another script. That shell script can be invoked by a human, *or the host computer* (think: scheduled jobs or cron jobs).

Since command line utilities can be used in so many use cases, it becomes simpler for the authors to simply mandate a path parameter or two. Depending on the utility, authors might choose to fall back to some default, but this is subjective. There is no single rule here. No authoritative guideline exists to determine how a utility should handle this.

Comment: Scripts. Managing the current directory, especially in larger scripts, can become significantly non-trivial. Or always `cd` in a subshell, which has it's own issues.

Comment: @jaskij Is it the program’s job to implement aids to overcome deficiencies in shells or other parts of the environment? It sounds more like a job for a standalone tool to alleviate.

Comment: @Glutexo thing is, a CLI option like `--cwd` is relatively trivial to implement, while providing a big QoL improvement to the user. It's less a matter of "it's not my job", and more a matter of simply having good UX.